# Overlapping Elements Bug

Tags: css

I have boxes that are filled with MySQL data. When the mouse hovers above a box, it becomes bigger, but the boxes on the line below move around the page. I'm pretty sure this is due to overlapping elements, but I don't know how to fix this due to them technically being all one element.

CSS

```
.boxed {
    border: 5px solid blue;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-top:10px; 
    height: 120px;
    width: 200px;
    border-style: double;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    float:left; 
}
.boxed:hover{
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #888888;
    border-style: double;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $selection = "ORDER BY  id ASC";

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if(!$conn) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $selection = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : "";
    if ($selection == "1") {
        $selection = "ORDER BY id DESC";
    } else if ($selection == "2") { 
        $selection = "ORDER BY id ASC";
    }

    $sql = "SELECT id, threadName, message FROM threads ";
    $sql .= $selection;

    mysql_select_db('threads');
    $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

    if(!$retval) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
      $id = $row['id'];
      $threadName = $row['threadName'];
      $message = $row['message'];
      echo "<div class='boxed'><center>".$threadName."<br>".$message."</center></div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my code?

Answer (score 0):

Give the box you don't want pushing other content around absolute positioning, then space the surrounding blocks with margins so the absolutely positioned box appears to be in flow with them:

```css
.boxed {
    border: 5px solid blue;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 120px;
    width: 200px;
    border-style: double;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: white;
}

.boxed:hover {
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #888888;
    border-style: double;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.below {
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.side {
    margin-left: 246px;
    border: .125em solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxed"></div>
<div class="side">
    this box isn't getting bumped
</div>
<div class="below">
    this text isn't getting bumped
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

For repeating code (i.e. from a PHP foreach loop) spacer blocks can be used to space the boxed blocks out, and on hover, jQuery adds the "hover" class to the appropriate spacer block, which gives it a style rule of `z-index:3` (and `position:relative` to activate the z-index rule):

```js
$('.boxed').mouseover(function() {
    $('.spacer').removeClass('hover');
    $(this).closest('.spacer').addClass('hover');
});
```

```css
.spacer {
    width: 210px;
    height: 130px;
 display:inline-block;
}

.spacer.hover {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}

.boxed {
    border: 5px solid blue;
    height: 120px;
    width: 200px;
    border-style: double;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    float: left;
    top: 0;
    background: white;
}

.boxed:hover {
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #888888;
    border-style: double;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.below {
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.side {
    margin-left: 246px;
    border: .125em solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spacer">
    <div class="boxed"></div>
</div><div class="spacer">
    <div class="boxed"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only thing is they're all technically the "same boxes" just filled with different things from a mysql database

Comment: yes, but I still seem to get an error once I put it into my own :/

Comment: It's likely your CSS is overriding some of these rules. I can't really diagnose it without seeing your code.

Comment: How so would you like to see my code. By the way I am ever so appreciative of you helping me out.